# Retrieving a list of all available SKUs from Google Play Subscriptions dynamically without manual input in Flutter/Google APIs

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-api, in-app-purchase

**Problem Description:**

I am trying to retrieve all the SKUs available in Google Play Subscriptions, but I don't want to use RevenueCat. Flutter provides an in-app-purchase plugin, but I couldn't find a way to display products using it. The same thing applies to Google APIs, where I have to provide the list of product IDs manually to get their details, such as title, descriptions, and price. I need a way to dynamically retrieve the available product IDs from Google Play Subscriptions.

**Desired Outcome:**

A solution that allows me to retrieve all the SKUs from Google Play Subscriptions dynamically without having to manually provide the product IDs.